# Can I display org-mode attachments as inline images in my document?

Tags: org-mode

I have image files that I have included as org-mode attachments. I would like to display them inline in emacs (as I could a hyper-linked external image).

Is there some standard way to do this?

Comment: Are you talking about sending emails, or are the images linked from a regular Org file?

Comment: I think the trick is to define a new link type for attachments http://orgmode.org/manual/Adding-hyperlink-types.html

Answer (score 8):

I wish it would be little [easier to found](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2008-11/msg00108.html), but all you have to do is:

1. Define new Org-mode [link abbreviation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Link-abbreviations.html), lets' name it `att`
2. Use it like `[[att:somefile.extension]]`

### Define new link abbreviation

```el
(require 'org-attach)
(setq org-link-abbrev-alist '(("att" . org-attach-expand-link)))
```

### Use it in link

Then you use it through `org-insert-link` as usually, just link type will be `att`. Here is simple example:

```
* TODO Some heading
:PROPERTIES:
:Attachments: someimage.png
:ID:       6b0817ee-27aa-4e7e-8a09-541ccbfee2c9
:END:

[[att:someimage.png]]
```

For image to actually display, I have to use `org-toggle-inline-images` after I add link even when I have `org-startup-with-inline-images` enabled. But it is same with every added image, not only those from *org-attach*.

*Edit: I found out that `org-attach` is not autoloaded on Org mode load. We need to require it or `org-attach-expand-link` function would be undefined.*

Comment: FWIW, org-attach was autoloaded for me when I tried this today.

Answer (score 5):

This is now built in to org. Use the `attachment:` link type. See: https://orgmode.org/manual/Attachment-links.html#Attachment-links

Answer (score 3):

The best I have found so far is to do it using `org-insert-link`. After having attached a PNG for example, the properties drawer looks like this:

```
:PROPERTIES:
:Attachments: ipython-notebook-in-emacs-with-ein.png
:ID:       91ededb1-20cc-4b88-9e6d-a03f48e985e3
:END:
```

I then do `M-x org-insert-link` (`C-x C-l`). When prompted, I select `file:` and then select the file in the subdirectory `data/91/ededb.../ipython...` (the `data` is standard, the `91` and the rest you can deduce from the ID and the attachment name).

After completing this, I am left with a `file:` link to the relative position of the attachment. With `M-x org-toggle-inline-images` you can make the linked attachment show up inline.